# Error addClass Jquery

Tags: jquery

I use bootstrap and Jquery 2.0, and when i try to submit a form add class "error" if the form is invalid. 
I dont know why this didn't work.Can you help me?

```
     function validate(){   
         if (isEmpty($('inputName').value)){
             $("#name").addClass("error");
             }
         }


     function isEmpty(texto){
        if (texto == null || texto.length==0 || /^\s+$/.test(text))
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

EDIT:

Why this work?

```
     function validate(){   
         if (isEmpty($('inputName').value)){
             alert("error");
             }
         }
```

And the addclass dont work:

```
     function validate(){   
         if (isEmpty($('inputName').value)){
             $("#name").addClass("error");
             }
         }
```

HTML:

```
      <div class="control-group" id="name">
        <label class="control-label" for="input">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: you only add the error class what would you like to do with the class?

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery object has no value property, what you want is the val method. Also `$('inputName')` would try to select a `<inputName>` element which you probably don't have, if `inputName` is an id the you can do

```
 isEmpty($('#inputName').val())
```

Comment: is `inputName` an element? Think OP might be missing a `#`

Answer (score 3):

Try comparing against `$("#inputName").val()` (notice the parenthesis). What you're doing is checking for the existence of a `value` attribute, which might be there, or it might not be, but it's not the value of the value, if that makes sense.

Comment: What does the function `estaVacio` return?

Comment: isEmpty() = estaVacio() i try translate name function.

Comment: `isEmpty` will return true if the string is "", null, or some other string of length 0.

Comment: @user2211163 this works because `.val()` is the jQuery function to retrieve the value off of an object. You could also do `$("#inputName").attr('value')` if you wanted to retrieve it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace

```
(texto == null || texto.length==0 || /^\s+$/.test(text))
```

with

```
$.trim(texto) === ''
```

Also don't ever use == or !=, use === and !== instead.